# Create several requests at once in Postman

Tags: api, postman, postman-collection-runner

I am trying to test GitHub API and explore it's different endpoints. I have the different possibilities which are returned by let's say the initial get request on `https://api.github.com`.

The returned list is:

```
{
  "current_user_url": "https://api.github.com/user",
  "current_user_authorizations_html_url": "https://github.com/settings/connectio                                                                                                                ns/applications{/client_id}",
  "authorizations_url": "https://api.github.com/authorizations",
  "code_search_url": "https://api.github.com/search/code?q={query}{&page,per_pag                                                                                                                e,sort,order}",
  "commit_search_url": "https://api.github.com/search/commits?q={query}{&page,pe                                                                                                                r_page,sort,order}",
  "emails_url": "https://api.github.com/user/emails",
  "emojis_url": "https://api.github.com/emojis",
  "events_url": "https://api.github.com/events",
  "feeds_url": "https://api.github.com/feeds",
  "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/user/followers",
  "following_url": "https://api.github.com/user/following{/target}",
  "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/gists{/gist_id}",
  "hub_url": "https://api.github.com/hub",
  "issue_search_url": "https://api.github.com/search/issues?q={query}{&page,per_                                                                                                                page,sort,order}",
  "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/issues",
  "keys_url": "https://api.github.com/user/keys",
  "notifications_url": "https://api.github.com/notifications",
  "organization_repositories_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/{org}/repos{?typ                                                                                                                e,page,per_page,sort}",
  "organization_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/{org}",
  "public_gists_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/public",
  "rate_limit_url": "https://api.github.com/rate_limit",
  "repository_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}",
  "repository_search_url": "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q={query}                                                                                                                {&page,per_page,sort,order}",
  "current_user_repositories_url": "https://api.github.com/user/repos{?type,page                                                                                                                ,per_page,sort}",
  "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/user/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
  "starred_gists_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/starred",
  "team_url": "https://api.github.com/teams",
  "user_url": "https://api.github.com/users/{user}",
  "user_organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/user/orgs",
  "user_repositories_url": "https://api.github.com/users/{user}/repos{?type,page                                                                                                                ,per_page,sort}",
  "user_search_url": "https://api.github.com/search/users?q={query}{&page,per_pa                                                                                                                ge,sort,order}"
}
```

Is there a way into ***Postman***, or follow up *facilitators* to generate a collection from these?. Some scripting will be necessary for sure to follow *Postman Json Collection format*.

If there is a solution other than Postman completely that fits in this issue, I am all ears.

*What I did:*

1. I tried to search for some *GitHub API* as a *Postman Collection*, I
   didn't find any.
2. I tried to understand Postman Json Collection format, which is not so easy for me to write some script to create one. Maybe someone did?
3. I can "find and replace : `"([a-z_])*":` with `curl -H "Authorization: token ####"`. Is there a way to integrate the whole to Postman?

I can't help it unless I consume a lot of effort. But also, I may be stuck other times as I'm exploring advanced API capabilities, techniques, and choices not only for *GitHub API*. So this won't be the last.

Comment: Sounds painful but have you tried manually creating a collection in the UI? Once you have the first one created with the headers, auth etc. You could duplicate it and just change the URL? Or create a data file and iterate through the URLs in a single request?

Comment: Sounds a good idea, I will try and come back for help or propose my own solution if it works well